# Generate mock forex or stock OHLC data to use in reproducible examples for pandas questions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### Summary

How do I create an OHLC dataframe using Numpy/Pandas

- which has an [ATR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_true_range) or trading range of somewhere around `.0075` to `.02` or range could be specified as a variable. Looking to see random price moves roughly within these boundaries.
- with a `Close` value on first row at `1.1904` (see example below).
- and can use a seed value (i.e. `np.random.seed`) so the dataframe is reproducible.

### Overview

I'm trying to generate mock forex data to create reproducible examples for pandas questions using Numpy/Pandas.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) covers similar data requirements but a Forex data example using Open, High, Low, Close Data could be useful and help avoid pasting large amounts of data into a question.

As an example of how the dataframe should look I see the euro/dollar rate on Friday was as follows:

```
eur = {"open" : 1.19160,
"high" : 1.19371,
"low" : 1.18739,
"close" : 1.1904}

pd.DataFrame(eur,index=['19/3/2021'])
```

[image: eurusd]

### What have I tried so far?

This is a fake/mock data example based on the previously mentioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that gives an idea as to what I am looking for in terms of how the data is generated with `np.random`.  I have added a resample and converted to OHLC but not sure how to generate/control the data with Numpy.

```
periods = 250

    eurusd = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( ['eurusd'], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(np.random.randn(periods).cumsum() + 10) })
    eurusd.index = pd.to_datetime(eurusd.date)
    eurusd.price.resample('D').ohlc()
```

[image]

### Edit

I have updated my attempt to generate this data (see "What have I tried so far" below) by generating OHLC columns after resampling to Daily from hourly data.  I am still working on the Numpy data generation element to generate a range of somewhere around `.0075` each day.

Comment: I think the last edit on this question removed too much context and prior work, so I have rolled it back, so that the history is not lost for future readers. In general, this ought to be kept - readers are usually the best judge of whether it is useful or not.

Comment: I've also moved the addendum to the end - new readers read questions top-to-bottom, and edits at the top tend to appear out of chronological order/context, making it hard to read. Put edit/update notes at the end if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my answer, but I'd be happy to see other answers where the code is refined/minimised.

```
def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 
   
    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = start_price+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    return fxDF
```

Generate dataframe with a seed to allow others to reproduce the data

```
df = genMockDataFrame(100,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=1)
```

Plot the data if required:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Ohlc(x=df.index,
                    open=df['open'],
                    high=df['high'],
                    low=df['low'],
                    close=df['close']))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

didn't change much. Just made the code more concise

```
def genMockDataFrame(days, startPrice, colName, startDate, seed= None): 
    
    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    
    P    = np.around(np.random.normal(scale= 0.0018, size= periods).cumsum(), 4)
    P[0] = np.around(startPrice, 4)
    
    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({
        'ticker': [colName] * periods,
        'price' : P,
    },
        index= pd.date_range(startDate, periods= periods, freq='H')
    )
    
    return fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite [Hammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250589/hammad)'s solution is shorter and more concise, I saw it has an issue where the second OHLC data always begin from zero.

Here's my solution after refining solution from [Hammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250589/hammad):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def genMockDataFrame(days, start_price, colName, startDate, seed=None):
    periods = days * 24
    np.random.seed(seed)

    P = np.around(start_price + np.random.normal(scale=0.0018, size=periods).cumsum(), 4)
    P = [round(i, 4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({
        'ticker': [colName] * periods,
        'price': P,
    },
        index=pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H')
    )

    return fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()

df = genMockDataFrame(100, 1.1904, 'eurusd', '19/3/2020', seed=1)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Ohlc(x=df.index,
                    open=df['open'],
                    high=df['high'],
                    low=df['low'],
                    close=df['close']))
fig.show()
```

[image: Sample generated chart]

Answer (score 0):

You could either sample EUR/USD as a random walk as you do above or use free quandl API to get historic midpoint values as your start and then sample `'True Range'` values from the normal distribution with mean `0.0075` and an appropriate standard deviation and simulate highs and lows from there:

```
import quandl as q
import numpy as np

df = q.get('ECB/EURUSD',
         start_date='2020-06-01',
         end_date='2021-01-06',
         api_key=API_KEY)
df['Sampled True Range'] = 0
df['Sampled True Range'] = df[['Sampled True Range']].apply(lambda x: x + 
np.random.normal(loc = .0075, scale = 0.005), axis = 1).clip(0.001, np.inf)
df['High'] = df['Value'] + df['Sampled True Range'] / 2
df['Low'] = df['Value'] - df['Sampled True Range'] / 2
df.describe()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPxVI.png)
You could also apply a random normal error to simulate `'Open'` values in a similar fashion.